# Exclude File Paths from Tailwind Config or PostCSS Loader

Tags: webpack, tailwind-css, postcss, postcss-loader

I am adding Tailwind to an Angular project, which I've done before on new setups without issue. The difference here is that I am adding our old bootstrap based theme to this project, and Tailwind. The idea is that we will slowly move to Tailwind over the coming months.

When I add Tailwind alone, I have no issues with the following `tailwind.config.js` file and additional `webpack.config.js` file:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  future: {
    // removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    // purgeLayersByDefault: true,
    // defaultLineHeights: true,
    // standardFontWeights: true
  },
  purge: ['./apps/**/src/**/*.html', './apps/**/**/*.ts', './libs/**/*.html', './libs/**/*.ts'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        xxs: '0.625rem',
      },
      colors: {
        'brand-color': 'var(--brand_color)',
        'motiv-blue': {
          lighter: '#8AC6F5',
          default: '#0094cd',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/ui')],
};

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: "postcss-loader",
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            ident: "postcss",
            syntax: "postcss-scss",
            plugins: [
              require("postcss-import"),
              require("tailwindcss"),
              require("autoprefixer"),
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

So those configuration files work great for a new project. However, when trying to add Tailwind on top of a separate theme, this doesn't work. I added the theme's `styles.scss` file to the `angular.json` configuration for this project:

```
"styles": ["libs/theme/scss/styles.scss", "apps/hsa-portal/src/styles.scss"]
```

And then served the project, but get the following error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find 'libs/theme/scss/brand-colors'
  in [
    /path/to/component
  ]
```

I tried adding the following `exclude` array (also just a single item) to the `postcss-loader` config in the `webpack.config.js` file, but it didn't solve anything:

```
exclude: [
  /libs\/theme\/scss/,
  /libs\/theme\/scss\/brand-colors/,
  /libs\/theme\/scss\/variables/,
  /bootstrap/,
],
```

There's got to be a way to either tell `postcss-loader` where to import these files from so that it works as expected, or to ignore those paths and just leave them alone. That's what I'm looking for, but I'm not very experienced with Webpack or PostCSS Loader.

### Edit

Changing the `webpack.config.js` file slightly, like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    postcssOptions: {
      ident: 'postcss',
      syntax: 'postcss-scss',
      plugins: (loader) => [
        require('postcss-import')({ root: loader.resourcePath }),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

Made the project build again but the Tailwind styles have disappeared. Essentially all I did was make the `plugins` attribute a function that returned an array, and set the root path for the postcss-import config.